Stuck at (erno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed,")
I'm new to learning Laravel 11, and I'm stuck with the (erno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed,") and despite trying various suggestions I’ve seen, I still can't resolve it. Could you please help me identify where I went wrong and how to fix it?
This is the expenses table
 public function up(): void
    {
        Schema::create('expenses', function (Blueprint $table) {

            $table->id();
            $table->increments('category_id');
            $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')
            ->on(table:'categories')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate(action:'cascade');
            $table->decimal('amount',8, 2); 
            $table->date('entry_date'); 
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->engine = 'InnoDB';

        });
    }

This is the categories table
   public function up(): void
    {
        Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {

            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('category_name'); 
            $table->string('description')->nullable(); 
            $table->timestamps();
        }); 
    }

I need the foreign key category_id in the expenses table to be connected to the categories table. When I update a category, I want the category_id in the expenses table to also update, and the same goes for deletion. If a specific category_name is deleted, I want the corresponding records in the expenses table to be removed as well.

$table->increments('category_id'); - what should that definition do on your expenses table?

I don't know because it said auto-incrementing unsigned integer as the primary key for the category_id field.

The category_id column, you declared in the expenses table can not be incremented. You have to define the following,
public function up(): void
{
    Schema::create('expenses', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id(); // Primary key for the expenses table
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('category_id'); // Set up the foreign key constraint
    $table->decimal('amount', 8, 2); 
    $table->date('entry_date'); 
    $table->timestamps();
    $table->engine = 'InnoDB';

    $table->foreign('category_id') // Foreign key reference to the categories table
        ->references('id')
        ->on('categories')
        ->onDelete('cascade')
        ->onUpdate('cascade');
    });
}


using $table->increments('id'); in one table and $table->unsignedBigInteger('category_id'); in another table will result in a foreign key constraint error.To avoid the error, you should ensure that both the primary key and the foreign key have matching types

If you want to keep the id as increments, you should define category_id as unsignedInteger

thank you so much for your help
